# Hosting a virtual machine in Russia

Tags: firewall, cloud, ip-blocking

One of the web-hosted projects I work on is being blocked in Russia (ostensibly due to Russia's attempt at blocking a certain messaging service.) The service must be accessible by ephemeral/mobile clients via SSH and HTTP.

I'd like to set up edge locations that are accessible from Russia, but I don't know how to verify whether the IPs are blocked or not. I was hoping to start a VM in a Russia-based cloud so that I can test this, but none of the cloud providers I would normally consider have any Russian presence. In fact, I'm having trouble verifying that *any* cloud providers have a Russian presence.

Basically, I'd like to know whether there's another way to find out if an IP is blocked in Russia, and barring that, whether there's a cloud hosting company with a Russian presence that will work with a US customer.

Comment: Does it have to be actual hosting? Cloudflare's network includes a Moscow edge location. https://blog.cloudflare.com/moscow/

Comment: Hosting would be preferable, since we're not using HTTP strictly. We're also using SSH - something I should have mentioned.